# need help understanding a short javascript script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Question 1: How does this code load css files asynchronously ? 
I understand that script files are loaded asynchrounously because of script.async = true; but can't seem to find a similar line for css files.

Question 2: if this script uses script.async = true; does it still work on the newer browsers since    async src"" exist or does this script cover it?

Question 3: does the script.async = true; only load javascript, jquery and ajax files asynchronously?

```
( function ( window, doc ) {

asyncLoader = function( urls, options ) {

    urls.foreach( function( i, file ) {
        loadFile( file, getExtension( file ), options );
    });

    // checking for a callback function
    if( typeof options.callback == 'function') {
        // calling the callback
        var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval( function() {
            if( doc.readyState === 'complete' ) {
                clearInterval( readyStateCheckInterval );
                    options.callback();
            }
        }, 10 );
    }
}

var getExtension = function( file ) {
    var extension = file.split('.');
    return extension[extension.length - 1];
}, 
loadFile = function( file, ext, options ) {
    switch( ext ) {
        case 'js' :
            loadJs( file, options );
        break;
        case 'css' :
            loadCss( file );
        break;
        default :
        break;
    }
},
loadJs = function( url, options ) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( script );
},
loadCss = function( url ) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( link );
}
// simple foreach implementation
Array.prototype.foreach = function( callback ) {
    for( var i=0; i<this .length; i++ ) {
        callback( i, this[ i ] );
    }
}
})( this, document );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The CSS file is loaded asynchronously because it is evaluated immediately when it is appended. Append does this asynchronously while the rest of the DOM executes. I've seen some people use this same trick with a  tag without using async = true and it seems to work as well without using async = true.
2. This still works on new browsers, even if you add the async attribute to your  or  tags. However, the javascript way is more of a workaround solution compared to using the new HTML5 async attribute and so solely using the async attribute inline is preferred if your not worried about supporting older browsers for async loading. The async attribute works much better and is built to work better and more intuitively with the DOM.
3. According to your switch statement, the script.async = true is only being called in the loadJs() function, which is only being called if the extension is '.js'. So yes, javascript, jQuery and ajax files will be loaded using script.async = true, because they have a '.js' extension, but so will any other '.js' file.

Here's a decent resource for more reading on the javascript async trick: [async-javascript](http://w3bits.com/async-javascript/)

Comment: 2. so instead of this script.async = true; I could have script.async; right? thanks for the above a lot

Comment: I don't know how script.async would work, but if you want to use the new async attribute, put async as an inline attribute like this: <script async type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>. I could be wrong, but the script.async = true may be adding that attribute in addition to running append.

Comment: I tried your current code using script.async=true and it is adding an async attribute to the script tag. You can probably avoid all of this javascript altogether and put <script async etc...> inline to just support newer browsers. If you want to load your javascript scripts dynamically but only use the inline async attribute and not use javascript at all for async loading, then you might want to consider writing a PHP (unless this is ASP.NET) function that will print them out dynamically. Then you can just add the async attribute and only use HTML5's async functionality to handle async loading

Comment: if I decide to use html5's async. How would you recommend going about with the css asynchronization

Comment: I would do it the same way. HTML5 using the async attribute for both <link async rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />

Comment: can you actually use async on css? i tried looking for it in the documentation and googling couldn't find it

Comment: I've seen async used on <link> tags before but I just did some searching and it looks like it is intended for scripts and I don't know if async,indeed does anything for <link> tags. I have never attempted async loading with CSS myself because CSS doesn't. Negatively impact performance, to the degree that JavaScript does. You may want to keep the JavaScript for CSS if async CSS is a must or try calling CSS at the bottom of the page.